# pandas timeseries splitting into many and taking the mean

Tags: python, pandas, optimization, split, time-series

I have the following pandas dataframe:

```
SEC POS DATA
1   1   4
2   1   4
3   1   5
4   1   5
5   2   2
6   3   4
7   3   2
8   4   2
9   4   2
10  1   8
11  1   6
12  2   5
13  2   5
14  2   4
15  2   6
16  3   2
17  4   1
```

Now I want to know the mean value of DATA and the first value of SEC for every block of the POS column.
So like this:

```
SEC POS DATA
1   1   4.5
5   2   2
6   3   3
8   4   2
10  1   7
12  2   5
16  3   2
17  4   1
```

Additionally, I want to subtract the DATA value of POS=4 from it's 3 prior DATA values, so where POS = [1,2,3].

Obtaining the following:

```
SEC POS DATA
1   1   2.5
5   2   0
6   3   1
8   4   2
10  1   6
12  2   4
16  3   1
17  4   1
```

I figured out how to do this by separating the dataframe in many different dataframes using a forloop. taking the mean and then subtract for the other dataframes. However this is very slow, so I'm wondering if there's a faster way to do this, anyone that can help?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another solution:

```
diff_to_previous = df.POS != df.POS.shift(1)
df = df.groupby(diff_to_previous.cumsum(), as_index=False).agg({'SEC': 'first', 'POS':'first', 'DATA':'mean'})
df['tmp'] = (df['POS'] == 4).astype(int).shift(fill_value=0).cumsum()
df['DATA'] = df.groupby('tmp')['DATA'].transform(lambda x: [*(x[x.index[:-1]] - x[x.index[-1]]), x[x.index[-1]]] )
df = df.drop(columns='tmp')

print(df)
```

Prints:

```
   SEC  POS  DATA
0    1    1   2.5
1    5    2   0.0
2    6    3   1.0
3    8    4   2.0
4   10    1   6.0
5   12    2   4.0
6   16    3   1.0
7   17    4   1.0
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! This is exactly what I was looking for. It runs fast and is just a few line of code.

Answer (score 1):

For your first problem, we can use:

```
grps = df['POS'].ne(df['POS'].shift()).cumsum()

dfg = df.groupby(grps).agg(
    POS=('POS', 'min'),
    SEC=('SEC', 'min'),
    DATA=('DATA', 'mean')
).reset_index(drop=True)
```

---

```
   POS  SEC  DATA
0  1    1    4.5 
1  2    5    2.0 
2  3    6    3.0 
3  4    8    2.0 
4  1    10   7.0 
5  2    12   5.0 
6  3    16   2.0 
7  4    17   1.0
```

---

For your second problem:

```
grps2 = dfg['POS'].lt(dfg['POS'].shift()).cumsum()

m = (
    dfg.groupby(grps2)
       .apply(lambda x: x.loc[x['POS'].isin([1,2,3]), 'DATA'] 
              - x.loc[x['POS'].eq(4), 'DATA'].iat[0])
       .droplevel(0)
)

dfg['DATA'].update(m)
```

---

```
   POS  SEC  DATA
0  1    1    2.5 
1  2    5    0.0 
2  3    6    1.0 
3  4    8    2.0 
4  1    10   6.0 
5  2    12   4.0 
6  3    16   1.0 
7  4    17   1.0
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! This is exactly what I was looking for. It runs fast and is just a few line of code.